# openlayers 4 projections

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, yandex

I can not understand the essence of the problem ...
There is a web page with openlayers 4, on it as a base layers I can choose Bing, OSM, Yandex and others:

```
        src = new ol.source.BingMaps({
        imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels',//'AerialWithLabels',
        key: '---'
    });
    bases["bing"] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        name: 'bing',
        title: 'Bing Maps aerial',
        is_base_layer: true,
        visible: false,
        source: src
    });

    src = new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        visible: true
    });
    bases["tf"] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        name: 'tf',
        visible: false,
        source: src,
        is_base_layer: true
    });

    src = new ol.source.OSM();
    bases["osm"] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        name: 'osm',
        visible: false,
        source: src,
        is_base_layer: true
    });
```

With Yandex is more complicated:

```
        var yaex = [-20037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244];
    proj4.defs('EPSG:3395', '+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');
    ol.proj.get('EPSG:3395').setExtent(yaex);

    bases["yandex"] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'http://vec0{1-4}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
            projection: 'EPSG:3395',
            tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
                extent: yaex
            })
        }),
        visible: false,
        is_base_layer: true
    });
```

I create a map as usual:

```
        var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attribution: false
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        target: 'map',
        layers: [],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })
    });
```

Everything works fine, I can switch the base layers, everything is correct.
Now I want to change the projection of the view to 4326:

```
view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326'
        })
```

All the base layers are displayed correctly, but Yandex is not displayed.
Chrome says:

```
proj4-src.js:1836 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null
at transformer (proj4-src.js:1836)
at forward (proj4-src.js:1875)
at ol-debug.js:5515
at ol.reproj.Triangulation.transformInv_ (ol-debug.js:67660)
at new ol.reproj.Triangulation (ol-debug.js:67720)
at new ol.reproj.Tile (ol-debug.js:70840)
at ol.source.XYZ.ol.source.TileImage.getTile (ol-debug.js:72003)
at ol.renderer.canvas.TileLayer.prepareFrame (ol-debug.js:69282)
at ol.renderer.canvas.Map.renderFrame (ol-debug.js:23128)
at ol.Map.renderFrame_ (ol-debug.js:31812)
```

Look more:

```
   function transformer(from, to, coords) {
 var transformedArray;
 if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
   transformedArray = transform(from, to, coords);
   if (coords.length === 3) {
     return [transformedArray.x, transformedArray.y, transformedArray.z];
   }
   else {
     return [transformedArray.x, transformedArray.y];// <--- ERROR HERE
   }
 }
 else {
   return transform(from, to, coords);
 }
```

}

transformedArray is null. null it is equal because transform() is called for point [0, -90], and Yandex has the extent [-180,-85,180,85], i.e. point outside the Yandex extent. I thought because of this, but I looked at Bing and they also had the same extent [-180,-85,180,85] as in Yandex.
If I give Yandex a projection of 3857, then everything starts to be displayed, but the problem is that Yandex is then have offset.
In general, I do not understand why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to use yandex layer with `EPSG:4326` attached on view and it works as expected. So it seems reprojecting tiles on client from 3395 to 4326 works fine.

This is the code I have used:

```
var yaex = [-20037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244];
proj4.defs('EPSG:3395', '+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.get('EPSG:3395').setExtent(yaex);

var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'http://vec0{1-4}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
            projection: 'EPSG:3395',
            tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
                extent: yaex
            })
        }),
        visible: true,
        is_base_layer: true
    });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [layer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
     center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/6L8ucvpz/) to see it working. Maybe you are using a wrong version of proj4js. Check the "External Resources" of my fiddle to view the proj4js library I am using.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It's worked for me! I used proj4 of 2.4.3 version. With 2.3.14 it worked fine.

Comment: glad to help my friend!